# Formatting the timezone in a way that is parseable

Tags: python, formatting, timezone, splunk

When retrieving results from Splunk, I get a `_time` field with the following value:

```
2016-08-26 12:50:03.000 GMT Daylight Time
```

As I'm in the UK and experiencing Daylight savings time, I know that should be a timezone of `+01:00`, however, I can't find any way to parse the timezone properly.

Splunk claims to use the the [TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), however, the string `GMT Daylight Time` doesn't appear in the linked Wikipedia article.

Can I convince Splunk to use ISO 8601 formatting? Failing that, are the TZ strings splunk uses a standard format that I'm unaware of?

As it stands, it looks like I'm going to have to build and maintain a list of timezones just to parse messages correctly, which seems like a lot of unnecessary effort.

In case it helps, I'm currently using the [Arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) library to handle dates, but can use another if required.

As requested in comments:

I'm POSTing the following data:

```
# self.filename is the path to the file I'm interested in. eg C:\Example.txt
# EventCode 4656 represents an access audit (raised when a file handle is requested)
{'search': 'search index=* EventCode=4656 Object_Name="{0}"| eval tztime = strftime(_time,"%Z") | sort -date'.format(
            self.filename.replace('\\', '\\\\')),
 'output_mode': 'json'}
```

To this url:

```
https://{server}:{port}/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export
```

Comment: How exactly are you fetching that string from Splunk?  Can you point at an API doc? Or are you screen scraping?  Note that the particular string you gave is a human readable `DaylightName` English localization of a Windows time zone entry.  It's not a very good one either.  It shouldn't be exposed over an API. If Splunk is doing that, show me where so I can go yell at them.  :)

Comment: @MattJohnson I've edited the question with more details. Thanks for identifying the source of the string. A quick Google seems to indicate a decoding nightmare involving a 3rd party database and tools (python on linux). If Splunk isn't parsing the date correctly on the way in, perhaps I can tweak the component monitoring the event logs to consume the date correctly? NB: Just stumbled across [your blog](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/07/working-with-time-zone-names-in-net/). Good article

Comment: I'll check it out later this weekend if nobody beats me to it.  Thanks for the details.

Comment: What does the raw data look like that you're searching? I'd wager someone didn't setup their props.conf properly to convert it into Unix epoch time on the way in